# JSONResult to String

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-2, serialization

I have a `JsonResult` that is working fine, and returning JSON from some POCO's. I want to save the JSON as a string in a DB.

```
public JsonResult GetJSON()
{
    JsonResult json = new JsonResult
    {
        Data = GetSomPocos()
    }; 
    return json;
}
```

I need to audit the response, so I want to save the `json` into a DB. I am having trouble finding a way to get the JSON as a string.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You're looking for the [`JavaScriptSerializer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx), which is used internally by JsonResult:

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(jsonResult.Data);
```

Comment: if only to do something as simple as convert array to json. this method is superb. doesn't need go for Json.Net

Answer (score 32):

You can also use [Json.NET.](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net.aspx)

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResult.Data);
```

Comment: I actually had a bug serializing with JavaScriptSerializer and the deserializing with JsonConver.DeserializeObject<T>(...).  Using this fixed it.

Comment: I noticed that JsonCovert returns more accurate result than JS serializer.

Comment: I've always used Newtonsoft's library (the JsonConvert parent namespace), and it has worked great! This is mostly just because I've been working in webforms, but even still, now that I'm into MVC4, I see no reason to switch . . . unless someone has a reason that I am unaware of?

Answer (score -14):

```
json = " { \"success\" : false, \"errors\": { \"text\" : \"绑定登录失败！\" } }";            
return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
```

Comment: Ignore this code.  It is not syntactically correct.