# XSS-safe JsonResult as string

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I changed my code to not need this answer anymore, but I'm still asking for curiosity's sake.

After much searching I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571985/jsonresult-to-string) and a few others like it. I've been looking for a way to take the JSON that would be returned by a JsonResult and use it in a view. The problem with that answer, and others, is they seem to be unsafe. Some sources I found suggested something like this:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

First of all, `Json.Encode` doesn't seem to exist anymore. Second, If I use Raw, then not only is the JSON syntax unencoded, the model contents aren't either. If a user enters a `<script>` tag into their information, it will get spit out that way and executed. If I don't use Raw, the JSON is escaped too by the view writer.

The reason I wanted this is because I have a page that's using some jQuery templating, and on first load, I wanted to still use the templates by having the view output a script tag that fired them.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very good observation that not all JSON output can be safely used in HMTL - and indeed, using a default configuration of even Json.NET (which is awesome) can lead to an XSS vulnerability.

Anyway, while there is *no advertising* about such, [`Json.Encode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode(v=vs.111).aspx) is *safe* to use in the construct `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(obj))` in a `<script>` context. (The result is also safe 'raw' in an attribute that uses single quotes, but not one that uses double quotes or no quotes.)

This is because `Json.Encode` applies \u-encoding to `<`, `>`, `&`, and `'` characters in JSON string literals (it also escapes the ASCII control characters and will thus play nice with XML as well). For example,

```
Json.Encode(new { hello = "\0\"\b\r\t<>&'" })
```

results in

```
{"hello":"\u0000\"\b\r\t\u003c\u003e\u0026\u0027"}
```

---

Since `Json.Encode` method does still exist it is likely that the containing assembly (System.Web.Helpers) or namespace was not correctly used.

I know this question is 3 years out of date ~ but since this question was the best one I could find after a short search and I had to hunt down an answer myself as many other sources containing hand-waving or ignore the issue entirely.. so yeah, I want a necromancer badge.