# ASP.NET MVC Return Json Result?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to return a JSON result (array);

If I do it manually it works

```
    resources:[
{
    name: 'Resource 1',
    id: 1,
    color:'red'
},{
    name: 'Resource 2',
    id: 2
}],
```

but I'm having issues rendering by passing it in:

On the view:

```
 resources:@Model.Resources
```

Which on the controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
...
var model = new Display();
model.Resources = GetResources();
}
 public JsonResult GetResources()
        {
            var model = new Models.ScheduledResource()
                {
                    id = "1",
                    name = "Resource"
                };
            return new JsonResult() { Data = model, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
```

on the model

```
public JsonResult Resources { get; set; }
```

But looking at whats rendered in HTML:

```
resources:System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSONResult to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571985/jsonresult-to-string)

Comment: It should be : return Json(new { Data = model } , JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Answer (score 84):

It should be :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetSomeJsonData()
{
    var model = // ... get data or build model etc.

    return Json(new { Data = model }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

or more simply:

```
return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I did notice that you are calling GetResources() from another ActionResult which wont work. If you are looking to get JSON back, you should be calling GetResources() from ajax directly...