# $.post does not refresh the View MVC Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

The view has 2 divs. One div displays textbox. The other displays text based on the Model.Flag value. On$post when I debug I get the inner and outer html as desired (with the second div text). But the view returned has only text box value and not the other div value. Since the variable (jq) has the correct data, can some one say if I have to rewrite the HTML on success of $.post by something like document.write ? The view is:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
{
%>
<div>
    The test message is <%= @Html.TextBox("Testname",Model.Testname)  %>
</div>
<%
if (Model.Flag)
    { %>
    <div>
        Print this as true
        </div>         
<%} %>
    <input type ="button" value ="ClickChange" id="btnChange" /> 
<% } %>

$(function() 
{
    $("#btnChange").click(function() 
    {
        alert("clicked");
        $.post("/Display/DisplayAgain/", { Testname: $("#Testname").val() },
        function(data) 
        {
            alert("success");
            var jq = jQuery(data);
        });
    });

});
```

The controller is:

```
public ActionResult FirstDisplay()
{
    TestWierd.ViewModels.DisplayViewModel dispModel = new  
        TestWierd.ViewModels.DisplayViewModel();
    return View("Details",dispModel);
}

public ActionResult DisplayAgain(TestWierd.ViewModels.DisplayViewModel dispModel)
{
    dispModel.Flag = true;
    return View("Details", dispModel);
}
```

I understand that $,post would refresh the entire view but this is not happening. Is my understanding incorrect. When I debug the view I get Model.Flag as true and when I add watch to the variable jq by debugging javascript, I get the inner HTML and outer HTML with the desired HTML i.e. with the textbox and its value as entered by user and the HTML "Print this as true", but on the browser I only see texbox with its value but not the other div with text "Print this as true".
 Am I doing something wrong. Can I not use $.post to check the model value and display text? Will it only have to be server side to refresh the view. Please help.

Comment: pleas add your DisplayViewModel code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got the contents you want to display in the variable `$jq`, you need to update the contents of the desired div.

Add an Id to the div so you can refer to it easily

```
<div id="Message">
     The test message is <%= @Html.TextBox("Testname",Model.Testname)  %>
</div>
```

then set the contents

```
//if the content is html then
$("#Message").html($jq);

//if the content is text (special characters like <> will be escaped automatically)
$("#Message").text($jq);
```

Note that if you want to keep the rest of the sentence, you can use a span with an id instead...

```
<div>
    The test message is <span id="Message">
        <%= @Html.TextBox("Testname",Model.Testname) %>
    </span>
</div>
```

To explain further... all AJAX methods (`$.ajax`, `$.get`, `$.post`, etc) cause the browser to open a connection to the server and read the response, however, none of them update the page automatically. If you want to cause a full-page refresh, you can use a form and [submit it](http://api.jquery.com/submit/). The Ajax methods just give you the response as a variable (be it text, html as a string or a complex object built from json) and let you use it however you wish (overwrite, append, use it in javascript to update lots of different ui components, etc, etc).

Because of this, it's usually simpler to use Ajax to talk to a service that responds either with json objects

```
{
    "TestMessage": "Some test message",
    "AnotherMessage": "Here I am"
}
```

or with just the part of the page you wish to substitute (eg omit `<html>`, `<body>`, etc)

```
An <span style="font-weight:bold;">Html</span> message to be injected into the page
```

If you want to return Json from your Asp.Net Mvc controller, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16836428/156755)

Comment: Yes used Json. Thanks a million for clearing the concept of $.post. It makes sense that any AJAX Method would not update the page automatically and easiest would be to use JSON

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help. Btw if you you're using Json, jQuery can inflate it as it's retrieved using [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)