# Using UIRouter templates with MVC 4 Routing

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create an ASP MVC 4 project with Ui-Router, however I've come across a problem.

My current server-side routing configuration looks like this:

```
    // Controller/Action route
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}");

    // Redirect any other routes to Site/Index so AngularJS can handle routing
    // Place routes above this otherwise they will be ignored
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Catch-All Redirect to Index",
        url: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Site", action = "Index" }
    );
```

And client-side

```
angular.module('loluk.home')
    .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('index', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: '/home/index'
        });
    }]);
```

`Site/Index`, the redirect action, simply contains the HTML file that has the ng-app directive. Any other actions/controllers will return API data, or a template. So, in my case, I have `Home/Index` which returns a template containing `<h1>Hello, World!</h1>`.

This is all fine and dandy if one of my states in ui-router requests "home/index" via templateUrl for my application. However, the problem I have now is that if I browse to `http://localhost/Home/Index`, I will see the template in it's raw form - rather than what I am expecting to see, which is the whole application in the `Home/Index` state. This makes sense as that is how I have configured it.

I initially thought "OK, well I can solve this problem by redirecting everyone to Site/Index (where the main file is stored) and using inline templates". Well, this works well, until you consider that

- The HTML file containing index.html is going to get ridiculously large and contain every template
- This breaks escaped_fragment crawling

So right now I am at a loss of how to make this work; I could use inlining, but that would make web pages load slowly and break SEO. I could stick with what I have.. but that will break any bookmarks that end-users create.

Making template calls a ChildActionOnly worked well until the fact that ChildActionOnly will return a server 500 (rather than a redirect), and UI-Router appears to not qualify as a "Child Action" as requesting the template through templateUrl also triggered the server 500.

I did come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766790/angularjs-routing-in-mvc-application-with-templates) question, however it doesn't express how exactly to solve the template situation.

Another avenue I have just pursued is having a templates area that contains all of my templates, and an api area that contains all of my api details (`/templates/` and `/api/` respectively). This solves the whole reloading page problem, though I am still unsure of how to approach the escaped_fragment crawling from this point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've accomplished this by creating two Areas in MVC - one for API that routes to `/api/` and one for Templates that routes to `/templates/`. AngularJS will make calls to `/template/{controller}/{action}` which will return a plain HTML view, and make RESTful calls to `/api/{controller}` for retrieving data.

It's not a perfect solution but it works.