# Convert JSON to string C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have webservice hosted on Azure which is returning a JSON object. The JSON response looks like this:

**HERE is my JSON RESPONSE**

```
{
   "Results":{
      "output1":{
         "type":"table",
         "value":{
            "ColumnNames":[
               "Accommadation",
               "Sex",
               "Age",
               "SiblingsAndSpouse",
               "ParentChild",
               "Fare",
               "Embarked",
               "Scored Labels",
               "Scored Probabilities"
            ],
            "ColumnTypes":[
               "Int32",
               "String",
               "Nullable`1",
               "Int32",
               "Int32",
               "Double",
               "String",
               "Int32",
               "Double"
            ],
            "Values":[
               [
                  "2",
                  "male",
                  "35",
                  "0",
                  "0",
                  "20",
                  "C",
                  "0",
                  "0"
               ],
               [
                  "2",
                  "male",
                  "35",
                  "0",
                  "0",
                  "20",
                  "C",
                  "0",
                  "0"
               ]
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Kindly tell me that how to convert this response to string in C#. I am new to this please help me out,help from you guys will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543324/how-to-convert-webresponse-getresponsestream-return-into-a-string

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSONResult to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571985/jsonresult-to-string)

Comment: This is not working Oceans.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing what your really asking is how do to deserialize the JSON.  Use [Newtonsoft's JSON library](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)'s DeserializeObject method and assign it to a dynamic object type.

```
dynamic dynamicObject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

then you can reference each property individually.

```
string type = dynamicObject.Results.output1.type;
```

Comment: Yeah! I want to Deserialize the json.
how can I access the values returned in the json?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`,

```
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
   String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```