# How to convert System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult`1[CustomType] into readable string

Tags: c#, json

I am getting output via method as System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult'1[CustomType]..How to convert this into a readable string? When I deserialize into a JSON object it's throwing me an error?

Is this a JSON object?

--Adding code

I am UnitTesting a method and that returns System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult'1[CustomType]

Here the FakeDetails method is called within GetFakeDetails

```
 A.CallTo(() => FakeTestInterface.FakeDetails(A<string>.Ignored)).Returns((CustomTypeData));
var a = await  Test.GetFakeDetails(InputData);
```

The value of a is 
System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult'1[CustomType]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONResult to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571985/jsonresult-to-string)

Comment: new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(jsonResult);

I tried the same and it's throwing me A circular reference was detected while serializing a object of type

Comment: Ok can you please provide your code like what have you done so far?

Comment: Added code to the question

Comment: What is the shape of your custom type. Also please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153385/a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-serializing-an-object-of-type-subsonic for circular reference error while serializing.

Comment: You have a circular reference.  You need to add your model code to the question.